# Combination Charts - Calculation with multiple THEN/OVER functions

Tags: charts, combinations, spotfire, tibco

I created a combination chart in tibco spotfire. 
Where I plotted the average with next formula:

```
Count([W/O]) / Avg([A/C Type Monthly FH]) * 1000 THEN If(Count([Value]) OVER (LastPeriods(1,[Axis.X]))=1,Avg([Value]),0) as [Average],
```

and the number of inspections by:

```
Avg([A/C Type Monthly FH] / 1000) THEN If(Count([Value]) OVER (LastPeriods(1,[Axis.X]))=1,[Value],0) as [No. of Inspections],
```

For my third graph in my combination chart, I would like to determine the Upper control limit by using next formula:

```
UCL = average + 3 * (sqrt(average / No. of inspections))
```

The problem is that i'm using THEN in two different ways. One for [values] and one for Avg[Values] so I cannot implement those functions at the end of the final UCL formula and not seperatly through the formula itself.

Does anyone know how to perform the UCL calculation, whithout creating a new calculated column. Many thanks!